Peach tree brown rot
I have older peach trees with a brown rot fungus. I was told that mycorrhizal fungi is good to help peach trees with brown rot but found no information on how to treat the affected trees with it! I was also told to add bark mulch, so should I mix it into the mulch?

https://gardening.stackexchange.com/ may be more appropriate, but we need a photo. mycorrhizal is about fungi on roots (and in any case some are very bad). Is the fungus attached on root? On trunk?
